# IoT Light Power Consumption

Tags: esp8266, power-consumption, lighting

I have a esp8266 which consumes around ~70 mA when active. I am controlling a light connected to it.

The deep-sleep can't be used here as the light has to be responsive to on/off signals.

- What is the best way to save power on the esp in this scenario?
- Is using light-sleep / modem-sleep a viable option here?

Comment: Same as always. Work out the latency and peripheral requirements of sleep, match the hardware state to this. I think the answer is self-evident once you identify these parameters, but feel free to extend the question to narrow it down a little.

Comment: Without knowing the system, there are several possible solutions. For example, light sleep reduces the power consumption to 1mA or less. But you need to present the system design and the vision for a viable answer.

Comment: modem sleep is automatic for station mode if not tinkered with. Mine seem to average 17ma over time, only burning 70ma during network times. I run an http server on them, so they don't need to keep sockets or mqtt going, but can still be "hit" quickly. Sometimes it takes about half a second to "wake up", but i can live with that or disable all sleeps on "critical" nodes.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to use an external interrupt that allows you to be in sleep mode and wake up when you press the ON/OFF button.

You can see this link, where it explains the use of external interruptions with the ESP8266: [Esp8266 external interrupts](https://techtutorialsx.com/2016/12/11/esp8266-external-interrupts/)

Comment: It is a wireless light, use of a switch is pointless.